# Problema con la Conexion a BD Postgresql con python

Tags: python, postgresql, eclipse

```
import psycopg2
class BaseDeDatos:
def _init_(self):
    try:
        self.conexion=psycopg2.connect(
            "host='localhost' port='5432' dbname='Inversiones' 
                          user='postgres' password='xxxxxx'")
        self.conexion.autocommit = True
        self.cursor = self.conexion.cursor()
    except:
        print("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos")
def crearTabla(self):
    crearTablaComando = "CREATE TABLE Pet(name varchar(20)[], age integer 
                                NOT NULL)"
    self.cursor.execute(crearTablaComando)


if __name__=='_Base_de_datos_':
     baseDeDatos=BaseDeDatos()
     baseDeDatos.crearTabla
```

cuando compilo, no me aparece ningun error, pero al ir a postgres, no me aparece la nueva tabla, y no se si no se esta conectando a la BD o si solamente no esta creando la tabla.
si no le pongo el if__name__... me sale este error:

```
self.cursor.execute(crearTablaComando)
AttributeError: 'BaseDeDatos' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

ayuda, por favor. Estoy empezando en python, asi que no sean duros conmigo :( jaja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema que encuentro es que es **__init__** (dos guiones bajos de cada lado) y no ***init*** (con un solo guion bajo de cada lado como escribiste) es por este motivo que no se crea nunca el cursor (ya que no se ejecuta el seteo de la conexión). Hice una prueba y si cambias eso y especificas correctamente los datos de conexion funciona OK.

```
 import psycopg2
 class BaseDeDatos:
    def __init__(self):
      try:

        self.conexion=psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' port='5433' 
                      dbname='Inversiones' user=postgres password=admin123")
        self.conexion.autocommit = True
        self.cursor = self.conexion.cursor()

      except:
         print("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos")
    def crearTabla(self):
        crearTablaComando = "CREATE TABLE Pet(name varchar(20)[], age integer NOT NULL)"
        self.cursor.execute(crearTablaComando)
```

Cuando lo ejecutas tenes que poner para que arranque o bien tambien puede ir sin el if.

```
  if __name__=='__main__':
     baseDeDatos=BaseDeDatos()
     baseDeDatos.crearTabla()
```

Copia mi codigo, cambiale los datos de conexión (ya que use los mios y ejecutalo. Adjunto evidencia[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí])